# how to use slider to rotate the joint in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i use the slider to change the joint angle, here is my code.

```
void Update()
    {

a = sliderx.GetComponent<slider>().value;
b = slidery.GetComponent<slider>().value;
headjoint.transform.Rotate(a, b, 0);
    }
```

and after I slide the bar, the joint rotates around and won't stop. like

a += value

and not

a = value

, the slider not give a definite number?

why? do I need to use eularangle?

when I use

```
headjoint.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(a, b, 0);
```

[image]

it's change the rotation angle of my object ,to 0,0,0 when running

anyideas?

Comment: "and after I slide the bar, the joint rotates around and won't stop" -> do you have `headjoint.transform.Rotate(a, b, 0);` in the `Update()` ?? Please show the whole monobehaviour snippet where you are handling the rotation

Comment: hi i had put it into the update()   @rustyBucketBay

Comment: I did not mean that you should put it there, I was asking, beacuse is normal that you have the rotation non stopped if its in the update. Please provide the whole snippet if you want accurate help. It is not possible to evaluate the problem with spare parts of the code not knowing where are they being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) as the name suggests rotates the object about a given amount. If you call this constantly with the same value your object is rotated constantly about the same amount.

You rather want to **set** a rotation.

Your attempt

```
headjoint.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(sliderX.value, sliderY.value, 0);
```

is actually close, yes. **But** by default `Rotate` is applied in **local space**. So if you want that same behavior you'd rather use

```
// First of all use the correct type and don't use GetComponent repeatedly
public Slider sliderX;
public Slider sliderY;

void Update()
{
    headjoint.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(sliderX.value, sliderY.value, 0);
}
```